# BLAZOR: Is it possible to change Display Format of <InputNumber>

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, .net-5

Is it possible to change the display format of `<InputNumber>` so that I can use N2 or C2?

I have the following code (`Amount` here is a `decimal`):

```
<InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Amount" step="0.01" />
```

I am currently using .NET5

Please help

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20210718162801/https://chanmingman.wordpress.com/2021/07/19/asp-net-blazor-thousand-separator/

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem but managed to solve it today. What I have is a HTML table with different HTML inputs. Its very dynamic. I decided to stick with the regular Input and not Inputnumber. My problem was the formatting being local, and using commas, and then having trouble converting the number into a float C# datatype.

My solution was applying LINQ directly on the value, and then also having an "OnChange" which updates, so it ends up working like a bind-value, but with some extra control over the updates. Here is my code:

```html
<input type="number" pattern="/^-?\d+\?\d*$/"
       readonly="@isReadOnly" 
       onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==8) return false;" 
       style="background-color:transparent; border:none; padding: 3px; width: 4em" 
       value="@cellvalue.ToString(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")).Replace(",",".")"
       @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => row.SetField<float>(col, float.Parse(__e.Value.ToString().Replace(",","."),new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))))" 
       size="8" 
       step=0.01 
       max="9999" 
       id="number" />
```

The CultureInfo added was my first attempted solution and I do not think it actually helps in any way or really does anything.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what N2 or C2 mean, but Blazor input controls can have whatever attributes a normal html `input` control would have.  Check out the HTML5 specs, and go ahead and add whatever you want.

My first search would be "HTML5 formatting number input," without reference to Blazor at all.

Also important is to check browser compatibility notes, in this case:
https://caniuse.com/input-number